# Angularjs template grunt-angular-templates generated cache path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

My file structure is like this.

- src

  - app
  - ticket

    - template.html
  - index.html
  - app.min.js

I am using [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) to create cache. My configuration is like this.

```
    ngtemplates:{
        app:{
            src: 'src/app/**/*.html',
            dest: 'src/templates.js',
            htmlmin: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true
            }
        }
    }
```

Bu this generates templates like this:

```
 $templateCache.put('src/app/ticket/template.html', '.......');
```

But it should be  `$templateCache.put('app/ticket/template.html', '.......');`

Can I change path with configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably work by specifying the cwd :

```
ngtemplates:{
        app:{
            cwd: 'src/',
            src: 'app/**/*.html',
            dest: 'templates.js',
            htmlmin: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true
            }
        }
    }
```